# Use \titleformat to format numbered chapters only

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I used the below code to format chapter headings

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% command + shape
{%
 \normalfont
 \Large
 \filcenter
 \sffamily
} % format
{%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter%
}% label
{
 1pc
}% separation
{
 \titlerule[3pt]
 \Huge
} % before
[%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \clearpage
 \addtocounter{page}{-1}
]% after
```

It formats the headings of table of contents and list of figures also. I don't want this format to be applied on table of contents and list of figures heading. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add code for the `numberless` variety. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]% command + shape
  {\normalfont\Large\sffamily\filcenter} % format
  {\vspace*{\fill}\titlerule[1pt]\vspace{1pt}\titlerule\vspace{1pc}%
   \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}% label
  {1pc}% separation
  {\titlerule[3pt]\Huge} % before
  [\vspace*{\fill}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage\addtocounter{page}{-1}]% after

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\normalfont\Huge\sffamily\filcenter}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test}

This is the text of the chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't like this very much, to be honest. Probably the “chapter 1” part should be higher and the title much farther than it and take the vertical center of the page.

Suppressing the page number is not a good idea, in my opinion.

Comment: Can you give the latex code for the suggestions you have made.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `tocloft` package which sets the ToC, etc., titles in the regular format.

```
% toctitleprob.tex  SE 577538

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}   %%%% new
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]% command + shape
{%
 \normalfont
 \Large
 \filcenter
 \sffamily
} % format
{%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \titlerule[1pt]%
 \vspace{1pt}%
 \titlerule
 \vspace{1pc}%
 \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter%
}% label
{
 1pc
}% separation
{
 \titlerule[3pt]
 \Huge
} % before
[%
 \vspace*{\fill}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \clearpage
 \addtocounter{page}{-1}
]% after

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

[image]